# PHP: Explode string on more than 2 dashes in string

Tags: php, arrays, regex, explode

I want explode a string to array with 2 dashes or more.
For example I have a string such as "size--medium" or "size---medium" or "size----medium" or this pattern with more than 2 dashes, I want explode them to:

```
Array(
    0 => size,
    1 => medium
);
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the input string according to two or more dashes.

```
<?php
$yourstring = "size----medium";
$regex = '~-{2,}~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $yourstring);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => size
    [1] => medium
)
```